# Bash syntax errors like `syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1 % 2 ")`

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error

Please tell why printing odd numbers in bash script with the following code gives the error:

> line 3: {1 % 2 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1 % 2 ")

```
for i in {1 to 99}
do
rem=$(( $i % 2 ))
if [$rem -neq 0];
then
echo $i
fi
done
```

Comment: Run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/. It finds two syntax errors.

Comment: For the source: There is no tax on white space; use freely when needed!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is working example:

```
for i in {1..99}
do
        rem=$(($i % 2))
        if [ "$rem" -ne "0" ]; then
                echo $i
        fi
done
```

1. used `for` loop have a typo in minimum and maximum number, should be `{1..99}` instead of `{1 to 99}`
2. brackets of the `if` statement needs to be separated with `whitespace` character on the `left` and on the `right` side
3. Comparision is done with `ne` instead of `neq`, [see this reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

As already pointed out, you can use [this shell checker](https://www.shellcheck.net/) if you need some clarification of the error you get.

Answer (score 11):

Not really sure why nobody included it, but this works for me and is simpler than the other 'for' solutions:

```
for (( i = 1; i < 100; i=i+2 )); do echo $i ; done
```

Comment: this is the best solution

Answer (score 6):

#### To print odd numbers between 1 to 99

```
seq 1 99 | sed -n 'p;n'
```

With GNU `seq`, credit to [gniourf-gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf)

```
seq 1 2 99
```

#### Example

```
$ seq 1 10 | sed -n 'p;n'
1
3
5
7
9
```

#### if you reverse it will print even

```
$ seq 1 10 | sed -n 'n;p'
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: With GNU `seq`, you can just do this: `seq 1 2 99`. No need for `sed`. But I'm not sure this answer is useful for OP.

Comment: or with current bash: `echo {1..99..2}`

Comment: @Cyrus: rather, `printf '%s\n' {1..99..2}`.

Comment: apparently the OP is new to shell programming. this answer is correct and cool but i don't think it's good or intuitive for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```sh
for odd in {1..99..2}; do echo "${odd}"; done
```

Or print in a cluster.

```sh
for odd in {1..99..2}; do echo -n " ${odd} "; done
```

Likewise, to print even numbers only:

```sh
for even in {2..100..2}; do echo "${even}"; done
```

OR

```sh
for even in {2..100..2}; do echo -n " ${even} "; done
```

Comment: did not work for bash, version 3.2.57

Answer (score 1):

Replace `{1 to 99}` by `{1..99}`.

Comment: that is not all what need to be fixed with that example, try it yourself with that modification

Answer (score 0):

```
for (( i=1; i<=100; i++ ))
do
    ((b = $i % 2))
  if [ $b -ne 0 ] 
    then
    echo $i
fi
done
```

Comment: I get "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `if'", whereas the solution from @DevDio above works.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..99}
do
    rem=`expr $i % 2`
    if [ $rem == 1 ]
    then
        echo  "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26594284)

Comment: @wscourge: Why not? It really would benefit from an explanation, and especially to set it apart from the existing answers. But it is an attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {0..49}
do
 echo $(($i*2+1))
done
```